# Print multiple data per ID in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vHHLrLdQBRgTliO_ZFmTUSTdkkWla8Lf982lG0MwJ0M/edit?usp=sharing), I have a sheet called **Form Responses 1** that contains the students' data and a sheet called **TEMPLATE** that contains the template that needs to be printed per student. The problem is that I can only print the spreadsheet one at a time by changing the data in the **C2** cell. Is there any way for me to print it quickly and easily to save time and effort?

In Google Cloud Print, I want it to say Page 1 = Student 1, Page 2 = Student 2, Page 3 = Student 3, and so on. Is it possible?

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about creating a new Google Spreadsheet including each page? When this is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const srcSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = srcSs.getSheetByName("TEMPLATE");
  const values = sheet.getRange("C2").getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0].getValues().flat().filter(String);
  const dstSs = SpreadsheetApp.create("tempSpreadsheet");
  values.forEach(v => {
    sheet.getRange("C2").setValue(v);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    const tempSheet = sheet.copyTo(srcSs);
    const range = tempSheet.getDataRange();
    range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
    tempSheet.getRange("B2:2").clear().clearDataValidations();
    tempSheet.getDrawings().forEach(e => e.remove());
    tempSheet.copyTo(dstSs);
    srcSs.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
  });
  dstSs.deleteSheet(dstSs.getSheets()[0]);
}
```

- When this script is run, a new Google Spreadsheet of `tempSpreadsheet` is created to the root folder. When you see it, each tab has each sheet without using the formulas. By this, you can print out the Spreadsheet by one manual process.

#### Note:

- When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, `/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */` is used in your script. When you use my proposed script, please remove `/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */`. By this, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` is automatically detected and used it. Please be careful about this.
- This sample script is for your sample Spreadsheet. So when the spreadsheet is changed, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [create(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#createname)
- [copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- [copyTo(destination) Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

Comment: But is it possible to only get the range and not the whole sheet? As per the image above, the row 2 is not visible.

Comment: @cjwrk Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. For `But is it possible to only get the range and not the whole sheet? As per the image above, the row 2 is not visible.`, I updated my sample script. Could you please confirm it? I really apologize for my poor skill.