# Google Sheets Format Date in AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is related with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69716741/16729249). I'm trying to export data on separate worksheet. When I export the worksheet, it works, but it does not copy the date format.

This is the cell's output after running the script and exporting it.

[image: Output]

```
function PrintMultiple() {

  const srcSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = srcSs.getSheetByName("TEMPLATE");
  const values = sheet.getRange("C2").getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0].getValues().flat().filter(String);
  const dstSs = SpreadsheetApp.create("SMRtempSpreadsheet");

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("About to take some action... Please wait...");

  values.forEach(v => {
    sheet.getRange("C2").setValue(v);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    const tempSheet = sheet.copyTo(srcSs);
    const range = tempSheet.getDataRange();
    range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
    tempSheet.getRange("B2:2").clear().clearDataValidations();
    tempSheet.getDrawings().forEach(e => e.remove());
    tempSheet.deleteColumn(1);
    tempSheet.deleteRow(1);
    tempSheet.deleteRow(2);
    tempSheet.deleteRow(3);
    tempSheet.copyTo(dstSs);
    srcSs.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
  });
  dstSs.deleteSheet(dstSs.getSheets()[0]);
}
```

However, when I format the cell as DATE, it looks like this.

[image: Expected Output]

How can I export it as a DATE without manually formatting each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLUTION THAT I USED:

```
var cell = tempSheet.getRange("D19");
cell.setNumberFormat('mm/dd/yyyy');
```